# PHP - proxy from live server to internal mapping server

Tags: php, networking, proxy

I've got a live PHP4.2.x server which I control fully.  I'd like to access our companies internal mapping server on 10.1.1.5  They don't want to open up to world, however are happy for my webserver to access it.

The 10.1.1.5 mapping server runs Mapserver 4 Windows.  http://www.maptools.org/ms4w/index.phtml?page=home.html

Have looked at cURL.. however proxying requests seems like it could be a nasty :-)  Especially with interactivity on the mapping side.. eg dragging maps etc..

Any elegant solutions?  Perpahs best one is to have mapping server live to the world with security?

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache has a module called [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) that does what I think you're asking for. I've successfully used it for similiar things in the past. This also gives you access to the full range of security measures supported by apache such as HTTP authentication.